# How to changes fonts using ttk themed widgets in windows

Tags: python, fonts, styles, widget, ttk

On OS X, `ttk.Style().configure('TLabelframe.label', font='helvetica 14 bold')` works to change the font used by the ttk.LabelFrame widget.  On Windows, `ttk.Style().configure('TLabelframe.label', font='arial 14 bold')` has no effect other than returning the same font info to `ttk.Style().lookup('TLabelframe.label','font')`.

I've tried different font names and formats, creating a derived style, using TkDefaultFont and just changing the size, and different widgets (TButton.label, TCheckbutton.label).  So far, no matter what I've tried, it always appears to use TkDefaultFont in the default size.

Changing the font setting in python27/tcl/tk8.5/ttk/xpTheme.tcl (the default theme on windows) does change the font being displayed.  Removing the `-font TkDefaultFont` setting from the theme settings does not change what is displayed.

Any suggestions as to how this actually works?

Edit: I hadn't tried changing the font for the Label widget before, and that one actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code in this area is buggy and will open a ticket.  Using 'TLableframe.Label' (note uppercase 'L' in 'Label' works.  'TButton.label' and 'TButton.Label' don't work, but just 'TButton' does; 'TCheckbutton' is the same.  I was unable to change the fonts for 'TEntry' with any combination, including adding 'textarea.'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for `ttk.LabelFrame`, you have to create a separate `ttk.Label` widget, and then assign it to the LabelFrame using the `labelwidget=` operand.  You can set whatever font/style on the Label widget that you desire and that will be reflected in the LabelFrame.  Note, you don't call the geometry manager for the Label widget.  Just instantiate it, then assign it to the LabelFrame.

This also means that you can assign almost any widget you want, such as a `ttk.Checkbutton`, if you wanted to control the state of child controls within the LabelFrame.  You'd have to write the code for this, but visually, it'd enable/disable the child controls based on the state of the Checkbutton.

Source: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-LabelFrame.html